# Remove span tag in string using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How to remove span tag from string using jquery?
I have multiple span tag in string variable

```
     <p>No Change<span style="color: #222222;">&nbsp;</span>
I love cricket<span style="color: #222222;">Cricket cricket&nbsp;</span></p>
```

Comment: ...include the value of your string variable

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If this is definitely just stored as a string you can do the following...

```
var element = $(myString);//convert string to JQuery element
element.find("span").remove();//remove span elements
var newString = element.html();//get back new string
```

if in fact this is already rendered html in your page then just do...

```
$("span").remove();//remove span elements (all spans on page as this code stands)
```

---

If you want to keep the contents of the span tag you can try this...

```
var element = $(myString);//convert string to JQuery element
element.find("span").each(function(index) {
    var text = $(this).text();//get span content
    $(this).replaceWith(text);//replace all span with just content
});
var newString = element.html();//get back new string
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/FytQy/) (you will see two alerts: string at start, string at end)

---

You can also just do this which might get the result you need:

```
var justText = $(myString).text();
```

Comment: I only want to remove span tag not its contents(text). Result of above string should be like "No Change &nbsp; I love cricket Cricket cricket&nbsp;"

Comment: @kashifilyaz: See my edit, I am just going to test this with a JSFiddle and will update with results

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kashifilyaz/GEFWG/  could you please check this,why alert show nothing.I used your demo just replace html.

Comment: In your working example,In 2nd alert <p> tag is not shown and one other thing if more then two p tags in inside div then 2nd alerts shows only 1st p tag.could you please check this

Comment: Your second example will strip <br> tags out of the span.

Answer (score 2):

This way you can keep inner text of the span by using .contents() jquery method (example of my code below):

```
$('#navc-22 > a > span').contents().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this;

```
var theString = '<p>No Change<span style="color: #222222;">&nbsp;</span>I love cricket<span style="color: #222222;">Cricket cricket&nbsp;</span></p>';
$(theString).wrap('<div />').find('span').remove();
```

...or would you like to keep it´s inner HTML?