# AngularJS: clean dom elements from include

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I need to clean span elements out of an HTML include, going by [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093838/remove-span-tag-in-string-using-jquery). However it just returns the first plain text string in the include and drops everything else (the include has over a dozen href links that I want to preserve).

```
  $scope.footermenu = function () {
      $http.get('includes/mainmenu.html').success(function(data) {
        var menusrc = data;
        $(menusrc).find('span').remove();
        var nospans = $(menusrc).html();
        return nospans;
      });
    };  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get replace() to work here in nearly 4-hours of trying every trick google could find, so I went back to the regex. I had forgotten that angular adds `class="ng-scope"` to every dom element under its purview (AFAICT), so I needed to stick that in my regex to get it working. Also note "msrc" is being pulled in from the dom, though this did not seem to make a material difference to the particular problem:

```
  $scope.footermenu = function () {
        var msrc = $('#menu').html();
        var nospans = function() {
          return msrc.replace(/<span class=\"ng-scope\">(.*?)<\/span>/g,'');
        }
        var mcln = $('<div/>').append( nospans() ).html();
        alert(mcln);
    };
```

A fair bit of clean-up needed and additional modifications to the footer code, but past that hurdle anyway. Thanks to @munsai for that rather crucial tip. It was pointed out [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331449/jquery-remove-element-from-string) that msrc !== $(msrc), so this solution bypasses that particular issue (assuming that info is correct).