# How to disable remove icon in ui-select2

Tags: angularjs, ui-select2

Is there a way to disable the icons in ui-select2? I am using ui-select2 in angular js, which is like adding tags while posting a question on stackoverflow:

[image]

How can I disable remove icon conditionally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Official website of ui select2](https://select2.org/)

[Edit 2018-11-12] You could always do a "display: none" on the x span:

```
span.select2-selection__choice__remove {
  display: none;
}
```

You could also use that to disable click on it with pure JS.

And there is also a "locked" option: http://select2.github.io/select2/#locked-selections
You can then control, per data, which one can't be removed from the selection.

Comment: The "allowClear option allows the user to remove selections. The question is about disabling remove icon, to disallow the user from removing tags.

Comment: The link you are posting is dead. This is an updated link: https://select2.org/selections#clearable-selections

Comment: Any news about this ? I am also looking for this functionality.

Comment: @hathija : updated my answer. You should be good to go with that. Let me know if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Could something like this help you? 
[Remove span tag in string using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093838/remove-span-tag-in-string-using-jquery)

It's not a direct answer, and it's not ui-select2 specific, but it should help you understand how to remove certain elements. You can just add a condition and that's that.

Answer (score 0):

This is also works

```
span.select2-selection__clear {
    display: none;
}
```