# Remove WYSIWYG HTML and CSS tags for Excel export

Tags: jquery, html, excel, wysiwyg

I have a form which has a WYSIWYG using http://summernote.org/#/. I used it for comments field in my form. I am using PostgreSQL 9.3 for database and saving the data from the comments field in a `text` datatype.

So as you expected when you save that to database, if the user has made changes of the format of the text like Font Style, Size, Line Breaks etc. the WYSIWYG will also add HTML and CSS codes on it and will also be saved together in the database. Then now I have this problem that when I render those comments in a Datatable the comments will look fine because the web interprets the HTML and CSS codes in it. But when I export the content to Excel, then my data is in chaos.

Excel won't interpret HTML and CSS tags and line breaks making my excel output broken. Lots of line breaks and everything.

Is there a way to strip those HTML and CSS? I want to do it when I am rendering it in a Datatables in jQuery so that when the Datatables load, the HTML and CSS is already stripped so I can just export it easily or even copy paste.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api/crm/detailedsummary", 
    type: 'GET',
    data: {"from" : $("#fromDateAll").val(), "to" :  $("#toDateAll").val()},
    success: function(result){
    var myObj = $.parseJSON(result);
        $.each(myObj, function(key,value) {
            table.row.add( [
                value.calldatetime, 
                value.phone_num,    
                value.agent,    
                value.gross_disposition,    
                value.net_disposition,  
                value.verified_status,  
                value.passwithchanges_status,   
                value.reject_status,        
                value.verified_by,  
                value.verified_date,    
                value.comments
            ] ).draw();
        });
    }});
```

The `value.comments` is the one with HTML and CSS codes in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) *may* work for this situation:

```
var comments = '<div id="someId">Hello <span>world!</span></div>';
console.log(comments.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,""));
```

The regexp checks the following:

- `<`       **:** left tag
- `[^>]` **:** anything except a right tag
- `+`       **:** one or more times
- `>`       **:** right tag

Comment: Hi thanks. Tried it but what about for css tags? like p { margin-bottom: 0.25cm; line-height: 120%; } . I can still see something like that in the columns.. Will acceept this answer though.,

Comment: Hmm.. I thought perhaps the css was inline, you might try something along these lines to remove `<style>` tags altogether - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093838/remove-span-tag-in-string-using-jquery  (assuming the css is inside `<style>` tags)