# Replace span tag and &nbsp from html string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML code like this:

```
<span>This is HTML.</span>&nbsp; This is &nbsp;&nbsp; paragraph.
```

And I want to replace the `span` tag along with `&nbsp;`.

My output would be like this:

```
This is HTML.This is &nbsp;&nbsp; paragraph.
```

This is what I've tried:

```
myvar = "<span>This is HTML.</span>&nbsp; This is &nbsp;&nbsp; paragraph.";
newContent = myvar.replace(/<\/?span[^>]*>/g,"");
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried yourself.

Comment: `myvar = "<span>This is HTML.</span>&nbsp; This is &nbsp;&nbsp; paragraph.";
myvar.replace(/<\/?span[^>]*>/g,"");`

Comment: Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093838/remove-span-tag-in-string-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) several times. Since, unless you use a regex, it only replaces the first occurrence of something, you won't lose the extra `&nbsp;`.

```
let initialString = '<span>This is HTML.</span>&nbsp; This is &nbsp;&nbsp; paragraph.';
let finalString = initialString.replace('<span>', '').replace('</span>', '').replace('&nbsp;', '');
```